# jquery/javascript insertion after reading text file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently working on a small script using jquery 1.11.0 and IE9. Basically its function is to read a CSV or text file.  The script basically reads the text file and displays it in IE.  You may find the sample content of the text file below.  I was able to read the file content and display it in IE with little issue however I'm having issues in inserting script on the string I extracted from the text file.

Text file content: `5:00,5,7,#5:30,6,8,#6:00,7,9,#6:30,7,10,#7:00,8,10,#`

```
var txts = "";
$.get("sample.text", 
      function(data) { 
        rows = data.split(",#"); 
        for (x=0; x<rows.length-1; x++){ 
          txts += "<tr><td>"+rows[x]+"</td><tr>"; 
        }
 });
 $("#output").html("<table>"+txts+"</table>");
```

It may not be the complete code but I hope you get the idea.  So, it will be displayed as a table a what I'm trying to do is to add a "tooltip" to each row that when you hover the mouse over to the first row, the tooltip should display saying "5:00AM - 5 eggs, 7 bacon".  I'm not sure where to begin in accomplishing this task.

Answer (score 0):

Split your data again around just a comma at each iteration of the loop.  You can then do whatever you want with it, like put it in "title" so it will show up as a tooltip.

```
var txts = ""; 
$.get("sample.text", function(data) { 
  var rows = data.split(",#"); 
  for (x=0; x<rows.length-1; x++) { 
    var tmp = rows[x].split(",");
    txts += "<tr><td title='"+tmp[1]+" eggs, "+tmp[2]+" bacon'>"+tmp[0]+"</td><tr>"; 
  } 
  $("#output").html("<table>"+txts+"</table>");
});
```

Comment: Updated to fix the problem Malvolio was kind enough to point out.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  For some reason <td title="Test"> doesn't seem display.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, as written, is not going to work: you declare and use the string `txts` outside the asynchronous function `get()`, but you actually populate the string inside the function (which will be execute *after* the `html()` statement.

It should look like this:

```
$.get("sample.text", function(data) { 
  var txts = ""; 
  var rows = data.split(",#"); 
  for (x=0; x<rows.length-1; x++) { 
    var tmp = rows[x].split(",");
    txts += "<tr><td title='"+tmp[1]+" eggs, "+tmp[2]+" bacon'>"+tmp[0]+"</td><tr>"; 
  } 
  $("#output").html("<table>"+txts+"</table>");
});
```